# What did Danny mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders-2017, iron-fist

In *The Defenders*,  when Madame Gao and the rest of the Hand reveal their use of

> dragon bones

to maintain their immortality, Danny says that

> they “desecrate Shou-Lao.”

What does he mean?

- Shou-Lao was alive when Danny did his trial and received the Fist.
- He was in K’un-Lun, not buried under New York for centuries.
- He’s called “the Undying,” so one presumes he doesn’t die easily.

Comment: Perhaps he's *"Undying"* the same way that Iron Fist is *"Immortal"*.

Comment: @Paulie_D - That’s fair…but one still has to explain how he went from a living dragon in K’un-L’un a decade or two prior, to a skeleton under New York in the present.

Comment: Leaving aside a writer's goof (not unlikely or a Finn Jones error) then my interpretation is that they desecrate the the *memory/spirit/whatever* of Shau-Lao.

Comment: In the comics (and so perhaps no relevant here), Shou-Lao [has died before](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Shou-Lao_(Earth-616))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically impossible to even discuss this question without sizeable spoilers, so if you're sensitive to that sort of thing, [turn back now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apxWU.png). You've been warned.

In [an interview](http://ew.com/tv/2017/08/18/marvel-the-defenders-finale-spoilers/) with *Entertainment Weekly*, showrunner Marco Ramirez unequivocally stated that the dragon under New York was *not* Shou-Lao:

> **That dragon skeleton — that wasn't Shou-Lao the Undying's, is it? It's just a pile of bones implying that there had been dragons all over the world and one wound up buried under New York?**
>
> Yeah, it's the second one.

Knowing that, we have to presume that Danny is using the word "desecrate" in a less literal sense. Without more information about K'un-Lun and Shou-Lao (which we don't currently have), it's hard to be totally certain of the intended meaning, but it's likely that he meant it in the sense of ["to treat disrespectfully"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desecrate); the other definition doesn't seem to make sense, for the reasons laid out in the question. And really, "disrespectful" is the *least* you could say about ingesting the remains of one of Shou-Lao's relatives.

The use of "desecrate" is a little bit odd, but it's not much stranger than anything else Danny says, and does seem to communicate just how reprehensible he finds their actions.